# How to insert into table asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to insert values from registration page into a table `login_tbl`:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

conn.Open();

string insertQ = "INSERT INTO login_tbl (empid,first_name,last_name,team_name,pwd,email_id,extension) VALUES('" + empbox.Text + "','" + fnamebox.Text + "','" + lnamebox.Text + "','" + teamnamebox.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + passwordbox.Text + "','" + emailbox.Text + "','" + extensionbox.Text + "')";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQ, conn);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Write("registration done");
```

I am getting error on the `com.ExecuteNonQuery();`" line. It is going into exception

> error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or
>   binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlExcep‌​tion
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Tds‌​ParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,

Comment: Care to tell us what is the exception error message ?

Comment: error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,

Comment: This means that your inputs are too long for the receiving fields. You can fix this problem and a more serious one called Sql Injection using a parameterized query where you specify for each parameter the type and the size of the value

Comment: ok..I will try what you said. and will calling stored procedure help solve this issue?

Comment: Check field length specified in table. Seems length specified for a field is not sufficient to store data mentioned in query. You can debug and find actual query to investigate which field got longer value.

Comment: Yes SP can help you to solve the problem if you specify the correct size for the parameters. But for trivial inserts like these i would not write a SP but a proper parameterized query applying the correct size for the parameters. You have a good starting point in the answer below. Also. If empid is numeric then I would make it an IDENTITY column and let the database choose a new value when inserting

Comment: Why do people still use non-parameterized queries ? P.S. Never Ever Use this kind of a query. Use parameterized queries, if possible then use Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are missing adding parameters here, and I'm wondering why you are not adding values like this :

```
VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";
```

I think it is more simple to add them this way?

Try this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
     connection.Open();

    string insertQ = "INSERT INTO login_tbl (empid,first_name,last_name,team_name,pwd,email_id,extension) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,@param5,@param6,@param7)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).value = empid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value=first_name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value=last_name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = team_name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param5", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = pwd;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param6", SqlDbType.Int).value = email_id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param7", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = extension;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Response.Write("registration done");
```

Comment: He probably wants `SqlDbType.NVarChar`, and will need to replace the `50`s with the actual sizes of the columns.

Comment: @DourHighArch that is true, I just provide an example how that should work, I guess he will figure it out, I really hope, but thanks for you comment to pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

One of the values is too long. You will need a server-side validation of the values you have to prevent the exception from occurring. Check for all the fields you intend to save whether they are valid from all aspects, including but not limited to their length. If they happen to not be valid, send a meaningful error message to the client-side and handle the problem there as well. Now, when you have fixed the cause of the exception, make sure invalid inputs are not sent from the browser to the server in the first place for all the cases where validity can be determined at client-side, this will reduce server-load by releasing the burden of all the invalid requests.

Now, when you have a validation, you will need to think about other aspects as well. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). You might either escape the values and handle them properly yourself, or use something which will do that for you, like [parameterized queries](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries). Since you have SQL injection vulnerability, it is safe to assume you have an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) injection vulnerability as well. Make sure you fix that as well, if you have it.